# how to restart (planned) a computer?

Tags: powershell

According to MS docs, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/restart-computer?view=powershell-6#inputs

```
Restart-Computer
```

is the command but the thing is i have two types of restarts on the server:

> planned
>
> unplanned

[image: restart types]

how can i specify the type so that its something like:

```
Restart-Computer Other(Planned) some_server
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is you can't; not with `Restart-Computer`.  You can, however, use the built-in Windows utility `shutdown.exe` to provide a reason.

In action:

```
shutdown.exe /r /f /m \\SERVERNAME /t 0 /d p:0:0 /c "Restart for maintenance"
```

Help document according to my Server2016 build:

```
Usage: C:\WINDOWS\system32\shutdown.exe [/i | /l | /s | /r | /g | /a | /p | /h | /e | /o] [/hybrid] [/soft] [/fw] [/f]
    [/m \\computer][/t xxx][/d [p|u:]xx:yy [/c "comment"]]

    No args    Display help. This is the same as typing /?.
    /?         Display help. This is the same as not typing any options.
    /i         Display the graphical user interface (GUI).
               This must be the first option.
    /l         Log off. This cannot be used with /m or /d options.
    /s         Shutdown the computer.
    /r         Full shutdown and restart the computer.
    /g         Full shutdown and restart the computer. After the system is
               rebooted, restart any registered applications.
    /a         Abort a system shutdown.
               This can only be used during the time-out period.
               Combine with /fw to clear any pending boots to firmware.
    /p         Turn off the local computer with no time-out or warning.
               Can be used with /d and /f options.
    /h         Hibernate the local computer.
               Can be used with the /f option.
    /hybrid    Performs a shutdown of the computer and prepares it for fast startup.
               Must be used with /s option.
    /fw        Combine with a shutdown option to cause the next boot to go to the
               firmware user interface.
    /e         Document the reason for an unexpected shutdown of a computer.
    /o         Go to the advanced boot options menu and restart the computer.
               Must be used with /r option.
    /m \\computer Specify the target computer.
    /t xxx     Set the time-out period before shutdown to xxx seconds.
               The valid range is 0-315360000 (10 years), with a default of 30.
               If the timeout period is greater than 0, the /f parameter is
               implied.
    /c "comment" Comment on the reason for the restart or shutdown.
               Maximum of 512 characters allowed.
    /f         Force running applications to close without forewarning users.
               The /f parameter is implied when a value greater than 0 is
               specified for the /t parameter.
    /d [p|u:]xx:yy  Provide the reason for the restart or shutdown.
               p indicates that the restart or shutdown is planned.
               u indicates that the reason is user defined.
               If neither p nor u is specified the restart or shutdown is
               unplanned.
               xx is the major reason number (positive integer less than 256).
               yy is the minor reason number (positive integer less than 65536).

Reasons on this computer:
(E = Expected U = Unexpected P = planned, C = customer defined)
Type    Major   Minor   Title

 U      0       0       Other (Unplanned)
E       0       0       Other (Unplanned)
E P     0       0       Other (Planned)
 U      0       5       Other Failure: System Unresponsive
E       1       1       Hardware: Maintenance (Unplanned)
E P     1       1       Hardware: Maintenance (Planned)
E       1       2       Hardware: Installation (Unplanned)
E P     1       2       Hardware: Installation (Planned)
E       2       2       Operating System: Recovery (Unplanned)
E P     2       2       Operating System: Recovery (Planned)
  P     2       3       Operating System: Upgrade (Planned)
E       2       4       Operating System: Reconfiguration (Unplanned)
E P     2       4       Operating System: Reconfiguration (Planned)
  P     2       16      Operating System: Service pack (Planned)
        2       17      Operating System: Hot fix (Unplanned)
  P     2       17      Operating System: Hot fix (Planned)
        2       18      Operating System: Security fix (Unplanned)
  P     2       18      Operating System: Security fix (Planned)
E       4       1       Application: Maintenance (Unplanned)
E P     4       1       Application: Maintenance (Planned)
E P     4       2       Application: Installation (Planned)
E       4       5       Application: Unresponsive
E       4       6       Application: Unstable
 U      5       15      System Failure: Stop error
 U      5       19      Security issue (Unplanned)
E       5       19      Security issue (Unplanned)
E P     5       19      Security issue (Planned)
E       5       20      Loss of network connectivity (Unplanned)
 U      6       11      Power Failure: Cord Unplugged
 U      6       12      Power Failure: Environment
  P     7       0       Legacy API shutdown
```

Comment: perfect, i was reading the documentation actually on MS then i saw you post heh. so from what i understand, this command is translated to: shutdown.exe /restart /force restart (close any apps running) /m (on the following target computer) \\SERVERNAME /timeout 0 seconds (restart immediately, dont wait) /document the reason as pLANNED because by default its unplanned:0:0 /comment "0 is Other(Planned) as major and minor reason integers"

Comment: also, based on MS docs, apparently if we wanna target multiple servers, we have to use this command in a script, so cant pass in a servers file, correct?

Comment: @Cataster `/c` is whatever you want to give as a reason for the shutdown.  It's already documented as planned based on the `/d` argument.  If you want to target multiple servers, you would need to do a `foreach` loop or something of that nature, yes.  Something like `foreach ($server in Get-Content -Path ./serverlist.txt) {`

Comment: great, btw, i kinda dont undertsand/confused about the major and minor reasons. whats the point of the integer reasons when passing p is sufficient?

Comment: @Cataster It creates different kinds of entries in the event log where this is logged.  There is a table that explains what each major/minor correspond to.

Comment: oh i see, its for the windows event logger

Comment: If there is a chance some one is using the computer I would give a time of 60 seconds. They will get a popup explaining why the shut down. Otherwise, carry on.

Comment: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1334887-restart-a-computer-remotely-using-powershell-and-prompt-for-computer-name-and-un